# Next button needs to be clicked twice before starting activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext

I have a simple `EditText` and then a button to go launch another activity.

- The first time the button is clicked, it clears the `EditText` instead of launching the next activity.
- The second time the button is clicked, it launches the next activity.

I'm not doing anything with the email address, because this is just a mock application for showing a concept, so I don't need to pass it to the next activity.

I can't figure out how to get the button to launch the next activity on the first press. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main11);

    EditText inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        if (email.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Please Enter Your Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Saved",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Backup3.this, Backup4.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        };

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you are not expecting a result when the next activity finishes you can use `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Why are you using startActivityForResult()? Also is the "email saved" Toast displaying when the email is not empty?

Comment: Shoul'nt EditText inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
be 
"final" EditText inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

how did your code compile???

Answer (score 1):

Check your layout file and try to **remove** the following attributes of the button

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: thanks - no idea how those properties got in there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I run this same code as yours and I didn't had the related problem. It all worked pretty well.

```
public class Backup3 extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                if (email.trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Backup3.this, "Please Enter Your Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Backup3.this, "Email Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Backup3.this, Backup4.class));
                };
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did change startActivityForResult to startActivity.  After looking at my files more closely, I realized that the error was in my layout file and not my activity code. Now it seems to be working okay.